# Configure alert on Google Cloud when 'n' objects did not get copied to Cloud Storage (GCS) on any given day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

Team,

I have a scenario to set an Alert on Google Cloud when 'n' files did not get copied to the bucket on any given day. Every day the files will get copied to different folder(object) inside the same bucket(I know the folder concept is just for visualization).

```
First day files : gs://test/2020Dec11/testfile1.txt and gs://test/2020Dec11/testfile2.txt 
Second day files : gs://test/2020Dec12/testfile1.txt and gs://test/2020Dec12/testfile2.txt.
```

Any given day if any one file/ both the files are not present in the bucket then it should send an alert. This Alert should trigger only once in a day may be around 11PM or 12Am telling the file/files are not copied for the previous day. I tried doing it by reading the log metrics but it is not working for one day when I give the period as '1 day' in the Alert policy. Please let me know if there is a better way than reading the log metrics

Any help is appreciated

Comment: When you use the log metrics, how did you set it up and what is the error you are getting and why did it fail? Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/guide-to-setting-up-monitoring-for-object-creation-in-cloud-storage) the guide you also followed?

Comment: Custom log based metrics is the correct way to achieve this. What's not working?

Comment: Yes i followed the same guide to set up alert.. The log metric is a counter metrics which reads the files in a bucket for "object.create". So when ever  a new file is created in the bucket it will reflect in log. @guillaume blaquiere I am not able to trigger it for just once a day. My Align period is 1 day and trigger threshold is < 2  for "1" hour. It is triggering multiple times a day instead of once a day. What should be by trigger duration as i see a maximum of 23hr 30 min in that. NO option to give duration as 1 day.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere To get it working for just once a day is not working. It is triggering multiple times a day.